# Parallelize tests (Cucumber 5, Junit 5)

Tags: junit, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber 5, Junit 5. I have written tests in feature-files.

Now I would like to do this:

- split my tests into several groups (for example, 2 groups: group1 and group2).
- specify different configurations for groups (for example: tests from group1 in sequential mode, tests from group2 in parallel mode).
- and eventually run all the tests (i.e., group1 will run sequentially, group2 in parallel).

Please tell me how this can be done on Cucumber5/Junit5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then thinking in groups of tests you should identify the resource(s) that should not be used concurrently. Once you've identified these resources you tag each scenario or with the resources that they use. You can tag all scenarios in a feature file by tagging the feature.

Then you can configure Cucumber to instruct the JUnit Platform to avoid scheduling these scenarios concurrently via `junit-platform.properties`:

```
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.<tag-name>.read-write=<resource-name>
```

For example when using:

```
cucumber.execution.exclusive-resources.reads-and-writes-system-properties.read-write=SYSTEM_PROPERTIES
```

A scenario tagged with `@reads-and-writes-system-properties` will lock the `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES` resource with a read-write lock and will not be concurrently executed with any other scenarios that lock the same resource.

See:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#exclusive-resources

Comment: hello @M.P. Korstanje  . 
Thank you for answering.
I decided, that at first I’ll try to just run a group of tests on Cucumber in parallel.